# Random 502 errors with Varnish

Tags: varnish

I have a varnish 4 in front of an Apache web server.
All is good, except i have some random 502 errors.

What is strange is that there is nothing in the varnishlog file for this error ! (all others requests are logged)

My parameters :
 VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=50
 VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
 VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120

What i can do in order to fix this ?

My default.vcl :

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8055";
}

backend php53 {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8053";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # Compatiblity with Apache log
  if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
  } else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
  }

  if (
    req.http.Host ~ "site1" ||
    req.http.Host ~ "site2")
  {
    set req.backend_hint = php53;
  }

  if (req.http.Host ~ "mainsite" ){
    if (req.method == "POST") {
       return (pipe);
    }
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/admin")) {
       return (pass);
    }
  }

  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD")
  {
    return (pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico)$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  } else {
    return (pass);
  }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
   if (beresp.http.Content-Length !~ "[0-9]{7,10}") {
     return(deliver);
   }
}
```

i have 502 errors on 'mainsite' (prestashop ecommerce, with lot of images)

My current stat :

MAIN.uptime             151353         1.00 Child process uptime
MAIN.sess_conn           59309         0.39 Sessions accepted

MAIN.sess_drop               0         0.00 Sessions dropped

MAIN.sess_fail               0         0.00 Session accept failures

MAIN.backend_conn              24076         0.16 Backend conn. success

MAIN.backend_unhealthy             0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted

MAIN.backend_busy                  0         0.00 Backend conn. too many

MAIN.backend_fail                 85         0.00 Backend conn. failures

MAIN.backend_reuse             53606         0.35 Backend conn. reuses

MAIN.backend_toolate           11249         0.07 Backend conn. was closed

MAIN.backend_recycle           64856         0.43 Backend conn. recycles

MAIN.backend_retry                 0         0.00 Backend conn. retry

MAIN.threads                     100          .   Total number of threads

MAIN.threads_created             108         0.00 Threads created

MAIN.threads_destroyed             8         0.00 Threads destoryed

MAIN.threads_failed                0         0.00 Thread creation failed

MAIN.busy_sleep                    3         0.00 Number of requests sent to sleep on busy 
objhdr

MAIN.busy_wakeup                   3         0.00 Number of requests woken after sleep on busy objhdr

MAIN.sess_queued                  11         0.00 Sessions queued for thread

ps aux | grep -i varnish | grep -v grep :

```
root     22319  0.0  0.5 121896 84060 ?        SLs  12:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P    /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 120 -p thread_pool_min=50 -p thread_pool_max=1000 -p thread_pool_timeout=120 -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G
varnish  22321  0.4  0.5 321348 92604 ?        Sl   12:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 120 -p thread_pool_min=50 -p thread_pool_max=1000 -p thread_pool_timeout=120 -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G
```

Comment: could be various reason, please paste your config file's to give you right direction. 
it could be temp error/ proxy error/ server overload or purge.

Comment: Yes, it could be various reason, like this one : https://serverfault.com/questions/582478/varnish-502-errors-on-large-files

Comment: Fix what? The lack of log entries in Varnish? Or the errors on the origin server?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into apache error log for "mainsite" ?

paste output of :

```
ps aux | grep -i varnish | grep -v grep
```

And see if your malloc size is not big to serve big contents size

Try: `beresp.http.Content-Length !~ "keep this size small"` (if that is the case)
Note: change that to regex to meet ur requirement where it says keep this size small

and check if you still get that error,

Comment: i add 
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.Content-Length !~ "[0-9]{7,10}") {
        return(deliver);
    }
}
then restart varnish : it's the same

Comment: nothing on apache log (which is normal because there is also no log on varnishlog ?)

Comment: doesnot sound normal if you have 502's and not see error log